# How to customize set pie graph colors using sql and c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, graph

I want to display customization pie graph which make user select option and display the graph depending on it 
in my case this is my data

[image]

I want the x axis is totalacheivment and y is ucp,ibnsiena,overseas

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Terriotry,UCPVol,IBNSINAVol,OVERSEASVol,TotalAcheivmentVol from ForecastTotal where Terriotry = '" + territory+"' and month ='"+Month+"' and year = '"+year+"'", conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                mydatareader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                while (mydatareader.Read())
                {

                    chart1.Series["UCP"].Points.AddXY(mydatareader.GetString(4), mydatareader.GetInt32(1));
                    chart1.Series["Ibnsiena"].Points.AddY(mydatareader.GetInt32(2));
                    chart1.Series["Overseas"].Points.AddY(mydatareader.GetInt32(3));

                    chart1.Series["UCP"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
                    chart1.Series["UCP"]["PieLineColor"] = "Black";



                         chart1.DataBind();

                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            conn.Close();
```

I Tried this code but only one color(blue) is displayed [image]

and i want to display each number by different color to know which number related to which column

Comment: For Pie Charts use only __one__ series! Also: You seem to be mixing Databinding the chart (better bind the points of a Series!!) and adding points. please decide which you want to do!

Comment: can u clear plz ? i don't know which is the best way can u post code ?

Comment: in my case i want to compare between 3 values how can i do this in one series ?

Comment: i did it in one series but how can i make each part unique i mean how can i put text on it

Comment: It is really hard to tell what you want as the code is so full of weird things that simply don't go together. The normal way is: a) throw away the Databind command. b) Use only one series to which you add points in the loop. They will automatically have different colors and appear in the legend. c) once you got that update the question and we can talk about styling and adding text.. [here are a few post about pie charts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+pie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TaW said in a comment, you only need one series for every pie chart.

This is how you can display a simple pie chart with text:

```
// Set up the series
var s1 = new Series("s1");
chart1.Series.Add(s1);
s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

// Get your data
var yvalues = new List<int> { 2, 3 }; // fill this list with data from your query
ar xvalues = new List<String> { "foo", "bar" };

// Databind it
s1.Points.DataBindXY(xvalues, yvalues);
```

As far as I understand your requirements you might want to have multiple pie charts: one for each territory and one for the comparison of the totals of the territories.